# c++ segfault in class vector

Tags: c++, vector, segmentation-fault

I've been playing around with making a game in c++ just to practice programing. I created a class that is essentially a 2d vector of cells that function as the different tiles of a dungeon. When I try to call my function to turn the edge cells into walls I get a segfault 11. From what I've researched the error is either trying to access an element out of bounds of my vector or I've run out of heap memory but I am uncertain if either of those is the case here.

```
int main(){
    floor myfloor(18,9);
    myfloor.setwalls();
}

#ifndef FLOOR_H
#define FLOOR_H
#include "cell.h"
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
class floor{
public:
    floor(int xmax, int ymax);
     void setwalls();
private:
     int sizeX;
     int sizeY;
     vector< vector<cell*> > layout;
};
#endif

floor::floor(int xmax, int ymax){
    sizeX = xmax;
    sizeY = ymax;
    layout.resize(xmax, vector<cell*>(ymax));

    for(int i = 0; i < xmax; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < ymax; j++){
            layout[i][j] = new cell();
        }
     }
}
void floor::setwalls(){
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeY; i++){
        layout[0][i]->setwall();
        layout[sizeX][i]->setwall();
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeX; i++){
        layout[i][0]->setwall();
        layout[i][sizeY]->setwall();
 }
}
```

What is causing the segfault 11 here? The testing I've done says that my program makes it to setwalls() but it seems to get a segfault as soon as it tries to access the first element of the layout vector.

Comment: Either out-of-bounds access or null pointer dereference.

Comment: `layout[sizeX][i]` and `layout[i][sizeY]` are out of bounds

Comment: I suggest that you do *not* use extraneous variables such as `sizeX`, `sizeY` to denote the number of entries in the vector.  A vector knows its own size by usage of the `vector::size()` function -- there is no need for the redundancy by using unnecessary variables.  By using unnecessary variables such as `sizeX` and `sizeY`, you are risking the chance of introducing bugs in your code if the vector happens to change size, and you didn't update `sizeX` or `sizeY`.

Comment: Also, if `floor` is constructed with the first argument as 0, all of those other functions will fail since the vector is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your doing a few things wrong so i wrote you an example on how to use multidimensional vectors.

```
#include<vector>
   #include<iostream>

 using namespace std;

 int main()
 {
     vector < vector < int >>myarr;

     myarr.resize(100);         // resizes 1st dimension 
     for (auto i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    myarr[i].resize(100);   // resizes 2nd dimension

// initilization
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
    for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++)
        myarr[i][j] = j;    // 0- 99 100 times.
     }

     for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
     {
    for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++)
              cout << myarr[i][j] << " ";

        cout << endl;
     }
 }
```

your not resizing your vector properly and your not initializing it properly  for how your using it. Also your type should be a std::unique_ptr and you initalize it with std::make_unique and both live in the memory header.

your code should be

```
 int main(){
     floor myfloor(18,9);
     myfloor.setwalls();
 }

 #ifndef FLOOR_H
#define FLOOR_H
#include "cell.h"
 #include <vector>
 #include<memory>

 using namespace std;
 class floor{
 public:
     floor(int xmax, int ymax);
      void setwalls();
 private:
      int sizeX;
      int sizeY;
      vector<vector<unique_ptr<cell*>>> layout;
 };
 #endif

 floor::floor(int xmax, int ymax){
     sizeX = xmax;
     sizeY = ymax;
     layout.resize(xmax);

     for(int i = 0; i < xmax; i++)
          layout[i].resize(ymax);

     for(int i = 0; i < xmax; i++){
         for(int j = 0; j < ymax; j++){
             layout[i][j] = make_unique(cell());
         }
      }
 }
 void floor::setwalls(){
     for(int i = 0; i < sizeY; i++){
         layout[0][i]->setwall();
         layout[sizeX - 1][i]->setwall();
     }
     for(int i = 0; i < sizeX; i++){
         layout[i][0]->setwall();
         layout[i][sizeY - 1]->setwall();
  }
 }
```

now your board will be the size in both deminsions you want it to be.

Answer (score -1):

The indices are 0 based. So, the valid values of bounds are 0<=bound<=(N-1).

You need to use sizeX-1 instead of sizeX. Same for sizeY.

Comment: his second dimension is size 0, all the time. he never resizes ANY of his second dimension.

Comment: @johnathan, for the scope of this question, my answer is perfectly valid. if you are in doubt, please refer to https://www.ideone.com/44CxDX